# Is there a method to draw a layout of a JavaScript project?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a method to draw the layout of functions and variables to understand a JavaScript project better?

Comment: What do you mean by mapping?

Comment: Contract a layout or a map for the functions, variables and files.

Answer (score 1):

Some IDE's are capable of at least draw rough outlines of a project. I'd recommend IntelliJ or Webstorm - right click on a file in the project-panel and choose **diagram**.

Then follow through.

[image: diagram of a component]